# Attributes for UTF-8 characters

Tags: c++, utf-8, ncurses

Ncurses can display characters with attached attributes via `chtype`s, which are constructed by or'ing a single character with attributes bitmasks thusly :

```
addch('a' | A_REVERSE);
```

However, after enabling UTF-8 support, pushing a multibyte character to the screen must be done via `addstr(char const*)`, and there is no room for attributes.

Is there a possibility of keeping attributes with multibyte characters, or should I just keep track of them myself and use `attron()`/`attroff()` when needed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually four character types which can be used with ncurses:

- `char` (for [`waddstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html))
- `chtype` (for [`waddchstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html))
- `wchar_t` (for [`waddnwstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addwstr.3x.html))
- `cchar_t` (for [`wadd_wchstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_add_wchstr.3x.html))

The `char` and `chtype` data came first, for 8-bit encodings. `wchar_t` and `cchar_t` came later for wide-characters.  The latter of each pair is essentially the former combined with video attributes and color.

ncurses differs from X/Open curses by allowing multibyte characters to be added via the `waddstr` (and `waddch`) interfaces.  Actually this would be the "**ncursesw**" library (the "**ncurses**" library does 8-bit encodings).

`wchar_t` holds more bits than `char`.

On Linux, `wchar_t` is (almost) synonymous with Unicode.  This is not necessarily portable, so ncurses uses the [wide-character functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/wchar.h.html) to convert from `wchar_t` as needed into UTF-8 — or whatever the terminal is using for its encoding.  Likewise, the input to `waddstr` may be UTF-8, but ncurses uses the corresponding multibyte-character functions for converting from your application's locale-encoding into `wchar_t` values.

Answer (score 2):

If your ncurses supports wide characters, then you can use routines like `add_wch` to add a single wide character, optionally with attributes. However, a wide character is *not* the same as a multibyte character; you would need to convert the multibyte sequences into wide characters in order to use them with `add_wch`.

See the standard library function `mbtowc` and `mbstowcs`, as well as their reentrant variants.